# MySQL query syntax Multiple where and or. Sanity Check?

Tags: php, mysql

My Query which I am sure can be optimized extensively but couldn't say how off the top of my head.

What I have is a post/comment like concept going on for my members. Where they can choose to share it with specific people or everyone. So from this I know my query can potentially cause duplicate results (if I could get it to work in the first place). I need to get a distinct 'ciID' while finding the users ID, along with any potential ID's mentioned else where. The ID's for the members are stored in 3 different columns for 3 different reasons.

mID is the member themselves, then sharedWith and whos_with kinda speak for themselves. I store the id's in sharedWith and whos_with like `1111:2222:3333` But in all I have to search across all 3 columns for the member ID shared, and whos column to make sure I get all the results for the ID's being passed through a function in an array. Which after building the query through a loop I come up with a query like

```
select DISTINCT(ciID),* from user_posting 
where (mID = 21 OR sharedWith LIKE '%21%' OR whosWith LIKE '%21%') 
or (mID = 22 OR sharedWith LIKE '%22%' OR whosWith LIKE '%22%') 
or (mID = 45 OR sharedWith LIKE '%45%' OR whosWith LIKE '%45%')
limit 1
```

somewhere in that I have a syntax erro I am not noticing, and I need a pair of eyes to help me out

Comment: Does this actually fail when you put it in phpmyadmin or on the sql command line?  I see youve posted you are using mysql, are you deffinately using mysql, if for example you are using mssql the limit wont work and would throw a syntax error. In mssql the equivalent is TOP

Comment: By fail I mean is it actually a syntax error, or are you just not getting the results you expect?

Comment: It is mysql not mysqli.. and the actual error is `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* from user_posting where (mID = 21 OR sharedWith LIKE '%21%' OR whosWith L' at line 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely wrong:

```
select DISTINCT(ciID),* from user_posting
```

It should be:

```
select DISTINCT(up.ciID), up.* from user_posting up
```

However I am not quite sure if that will return the expected results.

I think you need to re-design your table structure. Selecting with LIKE doesn't scale that good.

Comment: If it's all contained in one table there is no need to use aliases for the table and no need to use prefixes on column names.

Comment: @JonTaylor I am aware but he is doing `DISTINCT(ciID),*`. The `,*` does not work.

Comment: Yea Im already realizing what issues I am going to run into with the LIKE statements. Unfortunately the whosWith or the sharedWith can be a pretty big range of people, I was thinking about a 3rd table where I have a row per share or per who, but thats gonna make the table infinately large row wise, so I wanted to avoid that. Im still open to dev suggestions on the table though, sql really isnt my strongest suit